# Android CTS failures

Tags: cts

I have been running **CTS** tests **(Android L, CTS v7)** on Intel Baytrail based devices.

Host side setup is:

1.Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS.
2.Open JDK 1.6/1.7

While running CTS tests I face below frequent issues:

1. Tests get stopped after the device gets rebooted after 200 tests as per CTS tradefed framework.
2. I see a huge number of pseudo failures (generally not seen by other team when run at other location).
3. ADB does not work with super speed ports.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible reasons for the issues you are facing:

1. Device Presettings should be done in accordance to Google Recommendations:

   1. https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup
2. Check with the wifi connected to device is consistent during execution
3. Check out the display doesn't turn off during execution.